# if $\|AB\| / \|AC\| = \alpha$ show that $OB = \alpha OC + (1 - \alpha) OA$

Tags: vectors

Link to the diagram. Note: this is for self study.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFz18.jpg

[image: diagram]

How do i get started to solve this?.

$ AB = OB - OA $ -> eq(1)
$ AC = OC - OA $ -> eq(2)

Taking norm on both sides of the eq(1), eq(2)
$ \|AB\| = \|OB\| - \|OA\| \  (triangle \ inequality \ \|A - B \| \geq \|A\| - \|B\| )$ -> eq(3)

$\|AC\| = \|OC\| - \|OA\| $ -> eq(4)

$\|AC\| = \frac{1}{\alpha}(\|OB\| - \|OA\|)$  [since $\frac{\|AB\|}{\|AC\|} = \alpha $]

From eq(3)
$\alpha \|AC\| = \|OB\| - \|OA\|$

$\alpha (\|OC\| - \|OA\|) = \|OB\| - \|OA\|$

$\|OB\| = \alpha \|OC\| + (1 - \alpha) \|OA\|$ [since norm is positive]

$OB = \alpha OC + (1 - \alpha) OA$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to solve the second equation for $\alpha$:

\begin{align}
OB 
&= \alpha OC + (1-\alpha) OA \\ 
&= \alpha (OC - OA) + OA \iff \\
OB - OA &= \alpha \, (OC-OA) \iff \\
AB &= \alpha AC \quad (*)
\end{align}

Now we take the vector norm of each side:
\begin{align}
(**) \quad
\lVert AB \rVert &= \lVert \alpha AC\rVert \iff \\
\lVert AB \rVert &= \lvert \alpha \rvert \, \lVert AC\rVert \iff \\
\lvert \alpha \rvert &= \frac{\lVert AB \rVert}{\lVert AC\rVert} \ge 0
\end{align}

Alas we have to prove backwards. Thus two remarks:

If we define $\alpha$ by the right hand side, it must be non-negative, as a norm is non-negative, so we can drop the bars.

To make the step from $(**)$ to $(*)$ we need to know that $AB$ and $AC$ are multiples, this can be inferred from the diagram.

Comment: please comment on my solution

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know that the line segment between any two points $a$ and $c$ can be written as

$$b = ta + (1-t)c$$

where $t \in [0,1]$. In fact, we say that $t$ parameterizes the line segment.

Then to get started to solve this, notice what happens at the endpoints: when $t=0$ and when $t=1$. Once you have answered that, answer: what can we say about a given particular point in between the two, say $t=\alpha$?

Comment: Please clarify the parametric line approach

Comment: It is just an equation that is often taught. However, to fully understand the equation, re-read my questions that I asked already in my answer. If you can answer these questions, then you'll more fully understand "the parametric line approach".

Answer (score 0):

I would like not to give you the answer imidiately because this is a good excersice if u cannot then we talk about it. The hint here is that OB=OA+AB and that if you have a vector KL with ||KL||=1 RT=||RT||KL as long as they have the same adress. Now all u have to do is make what you have been given more simple.